# Problem with \SplitList in combination with \shortstack

Tags: xparse

I would like to achieve that a call to the user-defined command `\FooTwo{a|b|c}` expands to `\shortstack{\texttt{a}\\\texttt{b}\\\texttt{c}}`. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\Bar}[1]{\ItemDelim\texttt{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FooOne}{>{\SplitList{|}}m}{%
  \def\ItemDelim{\def\ItemDelim{,}}
  (\ProcessList{#1}{\Bar})}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FooTwo}{>{\SplitList{|}}m}{%
  \def\ItemDelim{\def\ItemDelim{\@stackcr}}
  \shortstack{\ProcessList{#1}{\Bar}}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

xxx

xxx \FooOne{a|b|c} xxx

xxx

xxx \FooTwo{a|b|c} xxx

xxx

\end{document}
```

The technique I employ seems to work well with `\FooOne{a|b|c}`, but not with `\FooTwo{a|b|c}`. The image below shows that the characters `b` and `c` are not placed in separate lines.

[image: Illustration of the problem]

What is the reason for this?

**Addendum:** There may be a much better way to achieve the goal I stated in the first paragraph of this question. I am open to any suggestion with or without using the `xparse` package.

Comment: You give no indication of the intended meaning but `\def\ItemDelim{\def\ItemDelim{\@stackcr}}`  the first definition will happen inside the group of the first cell of the table so will be lost as soon as `\stacckcr` is executed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The nested `\def` is intended to defer the definition of the new delimiter until the first item of the list has occured. Without using this technique, `\FooOne` for example would produce `(,a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\def\ItemDelim{\def\ItemDelim{...}}` trick doesn't work, because `\shortstack` is implemented with `\halign` and each cell forms a group.

Better using more powerful `expl3` functions. With `\seq_use:Nn`, the `\\` is inserted only between items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_matthias_foo_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \ttfamily
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_matthias_foo_seq { | } { #1 }
  \shortstack
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_matthias_foo_seq { \\ }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

xxx \Foo{a|b|c} xxx

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is just a toy problem and you want to process somehow the items, you can use a two-stage approach: first set a sequence with the “naked” items, then set another to one where the items are “dressed up”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{m}
 {
  \matthias_foo:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_matthias_foo_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_matthias_foo_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \matthias_foo:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_matthias_foo_in_seq { | } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_matthias_foo_out_seq \l_matthias_foo_in_seq
   {
    \exp_not:n { \texttt { ##1 } }
   }
  \shortstack
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_matthias_foo_out_seq { \\ }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

xxx \Foo{a|b|c} xxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your guess is correct. In the MWE, I stripped everything down to the `shortstack{}` problem that occured due to the groups. In real life, I apply some more processing to the items than just adding `\texttt{}` to them. Your second proposal looks quite flexible to me. It seems I have to get familiar with latex3 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly with this definition:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooTwo}{>{\SplitList{|}}m}{%
  \def\ItemDelim{\gdef\ItemDelim{\\}}
  \shortstack{\ProcessList{#1}{\Bar}}
}
```

Comment: Does this not expand to `\shortstack{\\\texttt{a}\\\texttt{b}\\\texttt{c}}`, i.e., does this not produce an empty line on top of the stack? This is why I have tried to employ the "deferred `\def`".

Comment: I didn't see an empty line when I compiled it, do you see one? Maybe one of the packages you loaded changes the behavior.

Comment: Okay I edited it. Now it doesn't include the first `\\ `.

Comment: Without the "deferred definiton" the top of the stack is slightly shifted downwards. Your version using `\gdef` works correctly. Thank you very much for your help.